# discord.js 14: How can I make my bot leave the channel after my bot finished playing an MP3 file?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My problem is when I do my slash command to make the bot enter in the vocal channel, I can't make it leave until the MP3 file is over. Here is the content of my JavaScript file:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, ChannelType, VoiceState, } = require('discord.js');
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { getVoiceConnection, entersState, joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource, VoiceConnectionStatus } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { join } = require('node:path');

const client = new Client({ intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
  ],
});

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('padoru')
        .setDescription('Elle est partout.....fuyez..')
        .addChannelOption(option => option.setName('channel').setDescription('Le channel vocal à rejoindre.').setRequired(true).addChannelTypes(ChannelType.GuildVoice)),


    async execute(interaction) {

        if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
            if (interaction.commandName === 'padoru') {
                const voiceChannel = interaction.options.getChannel('channel');
                const voiceConnection = joinVoiceChannel({

                    channelId: voiceChannel.id,
                    guildId: interaction.guild.id,
                    adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
                    selfDeaf: false,

                })

                const connection = getVoiceConnection(interaction.guild.id);

                const player = createAudioPlayer();

                let resource = createAudioResource(join(__dirname, '../../medias/sound_effect/padorupadoru.mp3'));

                try {

                await entersState(voiceConnection, VoiceConnectionStatus.Ready, 5000);

                console.log("Connected: " + voiceChannel.guild.name);

                } catch (error) {

                console.log("Voice Connection not ready within 5s.", error);

                return null;

                }

                connection.subscribe(player);
                player.play(resource);
                if (player.pause(), () => voiceConnection.disconnect());


            }
        }
```

I'm only finding older versions of [discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/) about how to do it, but in the v14, I didn't find much. I didn't find how to do it in discord.js 14.

I somehow managed to making it work, but with the setTimeout function. I am still reading the documentation, but I still don't find how to manage to leave the voice channel at the end of the song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To let the bot leave the voice channel once the bot has finished playing the MP3 file, we need to check that it is not playing (in discord terms: it is not speaking).
So you have to create a player `const player = createAudioPlayer();` which is used to play the audio and in the very next line you wrote if `player.pause` disconnect it.
So now think what are the options we can get. For me, I think there should be a  player.speak` or a event listener. So I checked the documentation and I found out that there is an event listener.

So the code will be:

```js
// Your code ...
connection.subscribe(player);
player.play(resource);

player.on('stateChange', (oldState, newState) => {
  if (newState.status === 'idle') voiceConnection.destroy();
});
// Your code ...
```

Comment: After looking again the doc, i didn't pay attention about the player status. Thanks for taking your time,  it's working perfectly !